# AndroidManifest.xml xmlns isn't working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, manifest

My manifest is interpreting my xmlns:android as an error, saying that I should "add Xsi schema location for external resource":

[image: Manifest error]

Could someone please tell me what's going on with my projects' manifests, it's really confusing since I don't know when this even started happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is this generated file?

Comment: Add full manifest while asking question so we can get a proper idea of your question

Comment: this looks like a generated file. it's better if you can add more insights of the issue

Comment: yes it is generated file. See the top

Comment: Problem 'fixed', kinda: the error disappeared because I think I was editing it in the wrong place or maybe it was a different manifest, like a build or something. Either way it's gone now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not worry about this file. On the top of the file, you see that is an auto-generated file. You need not modify it. If you modify it, then run your app, again it will be changed to what it was before. So you need not modify it.If you want the original manifest, below the code in the manifest, you will see two tabs named `Merged Manifest` and `Text`. The `Text`  is the one you need to modify. See the image below
[image]

See the bottom of the image. **Never ever bother about the Merged Manifest. If you do, you will waste your time**

Comment: I was already editing the manifest in text mode, that wasn't the problem; it's already fixed though. However, thanks for that information anyways!